# Special system of equations.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, systems-of-equations

There is given $n$ different odd prime numbers: $p_{1},...,p_{n}$.

When following system of equation is solvable?

$$\begin{cases} x-p_{1}=p_{2}^{a_{2}}\\x-p_{2}=p_{3}^{a_{3}}\\...\\x-p_{n}=p_{1}^{a_{1}}\end{cases}$$

Where exponents are natural numbers greater than 1.

I tried to do this for $n=2$ and it seems that it has no solutions

I will be gratefull if someone will help me.

Regards.

Comment: Please show us what you tried for $n = 2$ case, plus let us know where this question comes from. Thanks.

Comment: if $n=2$ then from two equations $$x-p=q^{a}$$ and $$x-q=p^{b}$$ i get $$p-q=p^{b}-q^{a}$$ And it seems that it has no solutions as $a,b$ are greater than 2.

Comment: It may seem so, but it isn't.  $13 - 3 = 13^3 - 3^7$.